# Deserialize Instant.ofEpochSecond() object format to Instant?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I have a following model defined

```
public class ItemDetail {
    private final String name;
    private final String id;
    private final Instant someDate;
}
```

I am setting `someDate` as `setSomeDate(Instant.ofEpochSecond(resultSet.getLong("someDate"))`. I am reading this from a database.

I am serializing this model to return the following response where `someDate` is assigned `Instant.ofEpochSecond()`

```
{
  "name": "Some nights",
  "id": "XYZZ01AS",
  "someDate": {
        "nano": 0,
        "epochSecond": 1292486400
    }
}
```

My client code parses this response and I am fine with the output.

Now, I want to test this and would like to deserialize this response in my tests. Assuming the above response is stored in the `response` variable.

```
String response = ..... //string containing json response same as above format 
ItemDetail itemDetail = objectMapper.readValue(response, ItemDetail.class);
```

This doesn't work even after registering the `new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())` (obvious).
It throws the following error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.Instant value
```

Is there anyway to make this work without implementing the custom deserializer?

**Note**: I just want to do this as part of the tests and don't intend to make any changes to the defined model ItemDetail.

Comment: How is `nano` involved?

Comment: Seems like the `JavaTimeModule` is not active during serialisation. The output shows the `Instant` is serialised using the default object serialiser. It should be `"someDate":1292486400.000000000`

Comment: @alexander.egger I am basically reading a long object from a database result set and then converting it to Instant as shown in the question (edited). Thanks

Comment: The problem is the nested structure. If you can't change the model, you'll probably have to do something like this: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaTimeModule should be active during serialization `new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());` . Otherwise the Objectmapper will convert Instant datatype to a nested object with `epochSecond` and `nano`

Comment: @Sachin - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014230/how-to-deserialized-instant-date-using-object-mapper-or-jackson ?

Comment: public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can us a Jackson MixIn like this

```
public abstract class InstantMixIn {

    public InstantMixIn(
            @JsonProperty("epochSecond") long epochSecond,
            @JsonProperty("nano") int nanos) {
    }

}
```

The following code shows the usage of this MixIn with your example

```
    ItemDetail itemDetail = new ItemDetail("XYZZ01AS", "Some nights", Instant.ofEpochSecond(1292486400L));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.addMixIn(Instant.class, InstantMixIn.class);
    String response = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(itemDetail);
    System.out.println(response);
    itemDetail = objectMapper.readValue(response, ItemDetail.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cant add an additional class. So, I think customized serializer is the only option

Comment: If you can use a custom serialiser you should also be able to use a MixIn. The MixIn does not mean you have to use InstantMixIn instead of Instant all over your code. It is only needed in that one line to tell Jackson how to handle Instant.